# Form partial error: undefined method `experiments_path' for #<#<Class:0x3ed3078>:0x3313200>

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, controller, partials

I can't find what I did wrong here, is there something I'm missing?

My new action/view here:

```
<h1>Submit a new experiment here!</h1>

<%= render "form" %>
```

My _form.html.erb form partial

```
<h1>THis is a form</h1>

<%= form_for(@experiment) do |f| %>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :title %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :title %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :description %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :description %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :plan %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :plan %>
  </div>
  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

My experiments controller:

```
class ExperimentController < ApplicationController

    def index
    end

    def new
    @experiment = Experiment.new
    end

end
```

And my routes:

```
  devise_for :users
  resources :home
  resources :experiment

  root to: "home#index"
```

I am visiting the following url:

```
http://localhost:3000/experiment/new
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In you want to follow rails convention then:

1. Rename your controller from `ExperimentController` to `ExperimentsController`, i.e plural `Experiments`.
2. Rename your controller file name `app/controllers/experiment_controller.rb` to `app/controllers/experiments_controller.rb`, i.e. plural `experiments_controller.rb`.
3. Update your routes by modifying `resources :experiment` to `resources :experiments`.

If not, update your `form_for` call as:

```
<%= form_for(@experiment, url: url_for(controller: 'experiment', action: 'create')) do |f| %>
  ...
<% end %>
```

Comment: I tried this and now I am getting a routing error that reads "uninitialized constant ExperimentsController"

Comment: Your file name should also be changed to `app/controllers/experiments_controller.rb` from `app/controllers/experiment_controller.rb`.

Comment: @user3408293, I've edited my answer to include the file name change.

Comment: I changed this and also changes the view/experiment to view/experiments file name. Now I am getting an unitialized constant ExperimentsController#new on the line in my controller that says @experiment = Experiments.new  Any idea whats going on?

Comment: Fixed it just changed my experiments controller line from           [at]experiment = Experiments.new to [at]experiment = Experiment.new

Comment: I think you're confusing yourself, the `Experiment` in `@experiment = Experiment.new` is the model class.  You are creating a new model class of type `Experiment` in `ExperimentsController`'s new action.  So change that line back to `@experiment = Experiment.new`.

Comment: Thanks you, that last comment really cleared up some misunderstandings